# asp textbox required field validator message positioning

Tags: html, css, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have used a asp:RequiredFieldValidator to validate a textbox. It works fine. But i need to change the position of the error message.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtGarageName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Garage Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="Garage Name" CssClass="form-control" Width="50%" ID="txtGarageName"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                      ControlToValidate="txtGarageName"
                      ErrorMessage="Garage name is a required field."
                      ForeColor="Red">
                  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              </div>
```

When i use this error message display starting from directly under the label. 
What i need to do is get the error message to display either in front of the text box or align it with the TextBox start point which means to alighn it more to right. I have tried using a css code as well as putting

> margin-left=""

which i saw as solutions in the internet. Neither worked properly.

Comment: try using a `class="span6"` for textbox and the same for the required field validator

Comment: in your case `col-sm-6` AND use `display=dynamic` in Required Field Validator

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh It didn't work. It will push the next controller(nest line label and text box) to right. Not the error message. Anyway these requiredfield validators ruin the layout. Do you have any other idea that can be used for validation purpose?

Comment: If the problem is that the error message doesn't fit in the available space the best `ErrorMessage` could be simply a `*` with `ForeColor=Red`

Comment: It worked. I didn't use it on text box that's why it dint work.Thanks @AbhishekGhosh

Comment: I will post an answer to this , if you could be kind enough to accept it ! :)

Comment: please see the answer which i posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `col-md-6` or `span6` CSS class for your TextBoxes will work for you

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="Garage Name" CssClass="form-control span6"  ID="txtGarageName"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                          ControlToValidate="txtGarageName"
                          ErrorMessage="Garage name is a required field."
                          ForeColor="Red">
                      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Although this solves the question there is a downfall. Since my form has more controllers ( 3 similar labels and text-boxes) its layout is ruined. Layout is fine only when the error messsages are displayed-  @Abhishek Ghosh

Comment: You could play around with the `span` classes to fit in your layout requirement , each span has a `width` assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid system 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

If you prefer a simple (non bootstrap) solution you should still use some placeholders for better formatting. An example that i found (not mine)
http://jsfiddle.net/dqC8t/1/

```
#wrapper {
width: 500px;
border: 1px solid black;
overflow: auto;
}
#first {
float: left;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
#second {
border: 1px solid green;
margin: 0 0 0 302px;
}
```